# need help extracting string from text

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract financial data from a wall of text. basically I have a function that splits the text three times, but I know there is a more efficient way of doing so, but I cannot figure it out. Some curly braces really throw a wrench into my plan, because i'm trying to format a string.

I want to pass my function a string such as:

```
"totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities"
```

and extract the following raw number:

```
"-2478000"
```

this is my current function, which works, but not efficient at all

```
def splitting(value, text):
 x= text.split('"{}":'.format(value))[1]
 y=x.split(',"fmt":')[0]
 z=y.split(':')[1]
 return z
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

sample text:

```
"cashflowStatementHistory":{"cashflowStatements":[{"changeToLiabilities":{"raw":66049000,"fmt":"66.05M","longFmt":"66,049,000"},"totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities":{"raw":-2478000,"fmt":"-2.48M","longFmt":"-2,478,000"},"netBorrowings":{"raw":-31652000,"fmt":"-31.65M","longFmt":"-31,652,000"}
```

Comment: this looks like JSON. By any chance did you omit the curly braces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using regex. It assumes the format is always the same, having the `raw` value always immediately after the title and separated by `":{`.

```
import re

def get_value(value_name, text):
    """ finds all the occurrences of the passed `value_name`
    and returns the `raw` values"""
    pattern = value_name + r'":{"raw":(-?\d*)'
    return re.findall(pattern, text)

text = '"cashflowStatementHistory":{"cashflowStatements":[{"changeToLiabilities":{"raw":66049000,"fmt":"66.05M","longFmt":"66,049,000"},"totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities":{"raw":-2478000,"fmt":"-2.48M","longFmt":"-2,478,000"},"netBorrowings":{"raw":-31652000,"fmt":"-31.65M","longFmt":"-31,652,000"}'

val = get_value('totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities', text)
print(val)
['-2478000']
```

You can cast that result to a numeric type with `map` by replacing the `return` line.

```
return list(map(int, re.findall(pattern, text)))
```

Comment: Nailed it, Thank you, you are a life saver!

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept any of the answers with the tick mark below the voting arrows, accept the one you like better, and change it later if a better one comes along

Answer (score 0):

If Buran is right and your source is Json, you might find this helpful:

```
import json

s = '{"cashflowStatementHistory":{"cashflowStatements":[{"changeToLiabilities":{"raw":66049000,"fmt":"66.05M","longFmt":"66,049,000"},"totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities":{"raw":-2478000,"fmt":"-2.48M","longFmt":"-2,478,000"},"netBorrowings":{"raw":-31652000,"fmt":"-31.65M","longFmt":"-31,652,000"}}]}}'

j = json.loads(s)
for i in j["cashflowStatementHistory"]["cashflowStatements"]:
    if "totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities" in i:
        print(i["totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities"]["raw"])
```

In this way you can find anything in the wall of text.

Take a look at this too: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp